# Conversion from query builder to eloquent model with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

How to convert the following query to eloquent model in Laravel 5?

```
    $city = DB::table('cities')
        ->join('provinces', 'cities.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
        ->join('countries', 'provinces.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
        ->select('cities.name as City','provinces.name as Province','countries.name as Country')
        ->where('cities.isDelete', '=', '0')
        ->get();
```

My table structures are:

1. Country:
       id,
       name
2. Province:
       id,
       name,
       country_id
3. City:
       id,
       name,
       province_id

I've done working with the eloquent model with 2 tables but I don't know how to manage 3 tables.
P.S. I have properly defined my relationships in model.

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes. For more info refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

```
 //Create this method in city model

public function province()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Province');
    }

//Create this method in province model

public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
    }
```

Now Try this query

```
$city = DB::table('cities')->with('province','province.country')
        ->where('cities.isDelete', '=', '0')
        ->get();
```

The resulted data will be in nested form

```
like cities
       -province
         ->country
```

Comment: Yeah. That's correct. I am getting the result in nested form. But i want only the specific columns just like I mentioned above in the select part. Using your query, it is returning whole table in nested form.

Comment: You need to iterate the data get the date in specific form or you collection method for this. Simply print data for that you can do this `foreach($city as $data){ echo $data->name; foreach($data->province as $province){ echo $province->name;  echo $province->country->name}  }`